# How to get a window handle of GTK# widget or container?

Tags: gtk, gtk#, libvlc, hwnd, gdk

I use libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd() function in GTK# (Xamarin). But I can't get a HWND of GTK# widget and set it in libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd() function.
In GTK+ I can use gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid(), but I haven't found this function in GTK#.

So how I can get a HWND of widgets or use this function for output media in the needed window/container/widget?

Answer (score 1):

You could always import gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid() manually from the library:

```
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity, DllImport(GDK_X11_LIB)]
public static extern IntPtr gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid(IntPtr gdkDisplay);
```

Where GDK_X11_LIB is a string containing the your gdk-x11 library. For GTK 2.0 GDK_X11_LIB would be "libgdk-x11-2.0.so" on GNU/Linux.

Comment: `gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid` was for gdk2, is there a solution for gdk3?